# ESPN API User Log In

Tags: authentication, oauth, user-accounts, espn

I am building an app using the ESPN API and I have run through all of the APIs, using all that I can. It's going to be a big, deep app, with relational connections between stories.

What I'm wondering is if there is anyway to allow the users to log in to their espn.go.com accounts via OAuth or the like?

This would be really convenient so that users can access their sports preferences, etc.. If not I can always use another backend provided to store user accounts / preferences. But I'd really like to be able to sync with their actual ESPN accounts.

Looking forward to the answer!

Cheers,
//MD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no public OAuth implementation for the ESPN API platform.

Comment: Are there any plans for it? Seems like a logical next step if you want more integration with the API.